# Installing miniconda with zsh

Tags: python, zsh, miniconda

I installed miniconda but i'm using ZSH and i'm having some trouble with the path.

In `.zshrc` I have this as the following path:

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Since I came from bash. I have node installed as well, I'm weary about changing my path though. At the moment my terminal does not recognize the command `conda`. Should I change my path?

Answer (score 9):

If you used the default installation of miniconda3, then it would have prompted you to install it in your home directory `$HOME/miniconda3/`. The binary is inside of the `$HOME/miniconda3/bin` folder.

So you need to add the following line to your `.zshrc` file to add the `conda` command to your shell environment.

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/miniconda3/bin"
```

By default, miniconda3 recommends put this folder at the front of your `$PATH` variable, which will effectively replace all the system tools with miniconda3's choices residing in `$HOME/miniconda3/bin`. If you want to allow this then use this more intrusive configuration in your `.zshrc` file:

```bash
export PATH="$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 8):

First add this line to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```bash
export PATH="~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Then navigate to miniconda3 folder and update it:

```bash
cd ~/miniconda3/bin && ./conda update conda
```

Finally there is script to automatically init conda for your shell:

```bash
./conda init zsh
```

Comment: I get this error: ```conda update conda```
zsh: command not found: conda

Answer (score 3):

The answer by gordinmitya is correct if not for a minor correction. But for completion, I would like to reiterate it.

**Step 1:** Add path to Miniconda in `~/.zshrc`

```
export PATH="~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

**Step 2:** Change directory to Miniconda Bin and update conda

```
cd ~/miniconda3/bin && ./conda update conda
```

**Step 3:** Initialize Conda for ZSH (automated script)

```
./conda init zsh
```

After these steps are complete, restart the terminal session and you should be able to use Conda on ZSH.